# rewrite my url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter  project
I want to rewrite my URL using htaccess. I have a URL like `abc.com/main/demo` and I want to change it to `abc.com/demo` 
I just remove the " main " .
how can I achieved it .

Sorry for bad English :(

Comment: is main a controller? if yes then you may have to set it as your default controller in application/config/routes.php and use the suggested .htaccess

Comment: main is the folder name that is located in controller's folder.... And demo is my controller name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ /$1 [R]
```

this will do the trick, or you can go to www.tossdown.com for more details**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, on second thought this is probably what you're asking for:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /main

    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And if you don't care about the index.php stuff, you can drop out everything after `RewriteBase /main`

Comment: mike ... i stuck in problem .. i much worried about this . i already have a .htaccess file i just include this code in my htaccess but i redirect me to 404 page not found

Answer (score 1):

You do not need mod_rewrite for simple redirects.

The apache instructions Redirect or RedirectMatch should be sufficient for you:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/main/(.*)$ https://my.website.com/$1
```

Here I use a 302 redirect, so that it's just a temporary redirect, when your website will be ok (and that redirection working), you should alter it in 301 so that it becomes permanent.

Now what we're all doing in our answer is how to tell your web HTTP clients to use the /demo url instead of /main/demo. But you're complaining about 404... well if you do not have a working index.php or index.html in the root /demo directory it's *'normal'*.

So I guess your question is not only how to redirect the user in another directory, but how to make your `/var/www/mysite/main/demo` directory (or something like that), with all the files in this directory, responding in the /demo/* url and not /main/demo/*. In this configuration we can guess `/var/www/mysite/` is your **DocumentRoot**. i.e. this is the root for your web server. The simpliest solution is to change this root by altering the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/mysite/main`. You could do that in the main configuration of your VirtualHost, maybe you could create a new VirtualHost for your project as well.

If you do not have access to apache main configuration but only to .htaccess and if you run several other websites in some others url we may find more complex solutions (with mod_rewrite redirecting physical directory path based on the website name for example). But you'll have to give us more informations if you want something more.

Comment: thanks regilero for detailed answer... i got it as abc.com/demo.But As i mention that i work in codeigniter. And after implement this piece of code it remove the "main" correctly , but it give me error that controller not found.. because my controller i lie in main folder :-(

Comment: @Hameed: the fact that your codeignitier codebase is not on demo but on main is veryyy important. Just working with apache you'll break things. You shopuld certainly find a solution in the way codeignitier handles urls and directories and not in apache withmod_rewrite. I cannot help you on that. But for sure if 'main' is an important information for codignitier to find your controller you'll have problems hiding this information (how can he knows where to find your demo controller?).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ /$1 [R]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . i add this code in my .htaccess but it not worked. its shows page with 404 page not found

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Does the website itself reside in `/main/` or `/`? Are your clients expected to go to `/demo` or `/main/demo`? Should clients be redirected from one to the other, or should both URLs work?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not the thousandth answer...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^demo/$ /main/demo/
```